# Getting the particular (pre-formatted) text (from a website) using JSoup

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

I'm new to JSoup, and I want to get the text written in this specific HTML tag:

```
<pre class="cg-msgbody cg-view-msgbody"><span class="cg-msgspan"><span>**the text I want to get is present here, how can I get it using JSoup?**</span></span></pre>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the css selector `.cg-msgbody.cg-view-msgbody>.cg-msgspan`

Comment: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Please post the code that you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
String html = "<pre class=\"cg-msgbody cg-view-msgbody\">"
       + "<span class=\"cg-msgspan\">"
       + "<span>**the text I want to get is present here, "
       + "how can I get it using JSoup?**</span>"
       + "</span>"
       + "</pre>";
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    //a with href
    Element link = document.select("span").last();

    System.out.println("Text: " + link.text());
```